# Como salvar um vídeo capturado pela webcam sem mostrá-lo usando OpenCV em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, visão-computacional

Estou começando a aprender Computer Vision. Estou usando o módulo OpenCV para Python 3. Lendo tutoriais, decobri o seguinte script:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Ele mostra imagens capturadas pela webcam e as salva em um vídeo. O script se encerra ao pressionar a tecla "q". Porém, eu gostaria de um script que salvasse o vídeo mas não o mostrasse. Tentei retirar a seguinte linha do script:

```
cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

Deu certo, porém o script não se encerrava mais ao pressionar a tecla "q", porque a tecla deve ser pressionada na janela que é aberta com a parte do script que eu retirei. Então como posso criar uma condição de parada sem criar a janela que mostra o vídeo?

Comment: Comente a linha `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')` em seguida troque a linha `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))` por `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', -1, 20.0, (640,480))` alterando o segundo parâmetro para `-1` e vaja se funciona.

Comment: Quando fiz isso, a diferença foi: ao iniciar o script, o programa solicitou que eu escolhesse um compactador. Depois que eu escolhi, o programa funcionou do mesmo jeito do anterior, @gato

Comment: Veja aqui na [documentação](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) este script, deixe um comentário aqui caso este script resolva seu problema.

Comment: O script do link que me mandaste é o mesmo script que eu quero corrigir, @gato

Comment: No momento estou sem webcan para testar, caso ninguém responder até segunda feira eu coloco uma recompensa, mas acredito que o problema e na condição mesmo. já que o comando que encerra o loop depende da janela. Vendo isso ficou mais claro para entender, então tem que pensar em outra forma.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema é que a função `waitKey` do OpenCV depende da existência de uma janela para capturar uma tecla pressionada (isto é, a tecla é de fato pressionada no contexto da janela que, portanto, precisa não apenas existir *como também estar com o foco*).

Se você não cria uma janela e usa essa função com um timeout (você usou 1 milissegundo), a função apenas espera o tempo e retorna -1 porque jamais uma tecla vai ser pressionada.

Se você deseja encerrar de forma "elegante" mas sem usar uma janela, uma sugestão é simplesmente capturar o sinal de término do processo no terminal (isto é, capturar o pressionamento das teclas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Eis um exemplo (que contém outras pequenas sugestões de melhoria também):

```
import sys
import signal
import cv2

end = False

# --------------------------------------
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    global end
    end = True

# --------------------------------------
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Tenta abrir a webcam, e já falha se não conseguir
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Não foi possível abrir a web cam.')
    sys.exit(-1)

# Cria o arquivo de video de saída
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

# Captura o sinal de CTRL+C no terminal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
print('Capturando o vídeo da webcam -- pressione Ctrl+C para encerrar...')

# Processa enquanto o usuário não encerrar (com CTRL+C)
while(not end):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        out.write(frame)
    else:
        print('Oops! A captura falhou.')
        break

print('Captura encerrada.')

# Encerra tudo
cap.release()
out.release()
```

Se esperar o pressionamento de <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> também não serve pra você, você vai ter que usar outra alternativa dependendo da sua necessidade. Você pode implementar um contador de tempo e encerrar após um intervalo pré-programado (usando [o agendamento de tarefas](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sched.html)) ou mesmo encerrar a partir da indicação por outro programa (usando [comunicação entre processos](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ipc.html)).

Comment: Estava esperando vc responder ;D +1